# BC30545 Visual Basic AND VB.NET Property access must assign to the property or use its value

Tags: vb.net

```
    My.Settings.Username = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.Password = TextBox2.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
```

In My.Settings.Save i have an error
 Although the values ​​are included

" Property access must assign to the property or use its value. "

Someone can help?

Comment: You didn't add a setting named `Save` did you?  If not, show us the exception stack trace.

Comment: Are the settings you are trying to change scoped to Application or User? I don't think you can change Application settings from code.